# gdb | view the variable argument list

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb, iokit

I as using the `bt` command to view the stacktrace. The output is

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x001ae4cd in Debugger (message=0x1 "???\a") at /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1228.7.58/osfmk/i386/AT386/model_dep.c:705
#1  0x3bf97000 in ?? ()
#2  0x0012b0fa in panic (str=0x5ef "") at /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1228.7.58/osfmk/kern/debug.c:274
#3  0x001a8cd4 in kernel_trap (state=0x51a67c80) at /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1228.7.58/osfmk/i386/trap.c:680
#4  0x0019ede5 in return_from_trap () at pmap.h:176
#5  0x00132bea in __doprnt (fmt=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>, argp=0x51a67e6c, putc=0x38ad24 <kvprintf+33>, arg=0x51a67e48, radix=10) at /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1228.7.58/osfmk/kern/printf.c:439
#6  0x0038ad11 in kvprintf (fmt=0x1 "???\a", func=0x1, arg=0x1, radix=1, ap=0x51a67e84 "\\?\034I\"") at /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1228.7.58/bsd/kern/subr_prf.c:525
#7  0x491b5dac in com_my_drv_Log (format=0x491cbff8 "%s::%s:%n\n") at Logger.cpp:37
#8  0x491b3d36 in MyDrv::init (this=0x5c1f200, properties=0x58a8040) at MyDrv.cpp:34
#9  0x00412887 in IOService::probeCandidates (this=0x599a980, matches=0x58ade80) at /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1228.7.58/iokit/Kernel/IOService.cpp:2512
#10 0x004124ab in IOService::doServiceMatch (this=0x534180, options=8) at /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1228.7.58/iokit/Kernel/IOService.cpp:2921
#11 0x00411127 in _IOConfigThread::main (self=0x58c6790) at /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1228.7.58/iokit/Kernel/IOService.cpp:3125
(gdb)
```

In frame

```
#7  0x491b5dac in com_my_drv_Log
```

how could I view the parameters passed to my `com_my_drv_Log` with signature

```
void com_my_drv_Log (const char* format, ...);
/* with the variable argument list */
```

?

Comment: possibly relevant: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/220209-gdb-of-va-alist.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like this is possible to do it for a simple program like this:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(const char *fmt, ...)
{
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, fmt);
        vprintf(fmt, args);
        va_end(args);
        return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        myfunc("test 1: %s %s\n", "one", "two");
        myfunc("test 2: %s %d %c\n", "apple", 222, 'y');
        return 0;
}
```

Here is sample gdb session:

```
$ gdb testprog
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.1-debian
[snip]
Reading symbols from /home/user/testprog...done.
(gdb) break myfunc
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400552: file testprog.c, line 7.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/user/testprog

Breakpoint 1, myfunc (fmt=0x4006f4 "test 1: %s %s\n") at testprog.c:7
7               va_start(args, fmt);
(gdb) # initialize args to hold correct values:
(gdb) step
8               vprintf(fmt, args);
(gdb) # print first argument in "..." list which we know is a char*:
(gdb) p *(char **)(((char *)args[0].reg_save_area)+args[0].gp_offset)
$1 = 0x4006f0 "one"
```

I have not tested all of this, look this [link](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/gdb/2010-07/msg00075.html) for full solution. [This blog](http://www.moythreads.com/wordpress/2008/05/) will be useful also.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me, there was also useful to view `<cstdarg>` header.

Answer (score 3):

```
(gdb) frame 8
```

will put you in the frame of the caller.   Examine the arguments that are being passed.

Comment: I think the question is centered on variable argument lists (the infamous `...`) and the OP already knows how to view arguments in the general case.

Comment: The easiest way to look at the arguments passed to a variadic function is to go up one level in the call stack.  It's a simple solution; why bother with trying to do it from within the variadic function?

Comment: @WilliamPursell when the argument to the variadic function is an function itself, in the level up you will se only the function name, not its return value (e.g. `printf("%s", getString())`