# Stopping on breakpoint in a variable arguments function

Tags: c, debugging, list, arguments

I have a following function and I want to stop for debugging inside of it depending on content of variable arguments passed to it.

```
int
my_fprintf (const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list arg_list;
  ...
  va_start (arg_list, format);
  result = vfprintf (stream, indent_str, arg_list);
  va_end (arg_list);

  ...
  return result;
}
```

What I want is to put a breakpoint in it to stop if the call is `my_fprintf ("%s", "hello")` for example (so breakpoint condition would be as close as possible to a `<smth> == "hello"`).

Is it possible to do that?

Updates:

- Debugger is gdb.
- I know how to set conditional breakpoints, I want to know, that the condition should be in this case.

Comment: You might find it relevant to state exactly what debugger you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gdb can do that. You just need a variable (`p` in the following snippet) that you can check. To successfully obtain `p`, you would need more goo, namely, checking that the first argument of arg2 is a char* within reason, done here by checking that `format` contains `%s` for example (though %s is not sufficient, as someone may use %.*s or something).

```
static int my_fprintf(const char *format, ...)
{
        const char *p;
        va_list arg_list, arg2;
        bool have_string = false;

        va_start(arg_list, format);
        va_copy(arg2, arg_list);
        for (p = strchr(format, '%'); p != NULL; p = strchr(p+1, '%')) {
                if (p[1] == '%')
                        continue;
                if (p[1] != 's')
                        break;
                have_string = true;
                break;
        }
        if (have_string)
                p = va_arg(arg2, const char *);
        result = vfprintf(stream, indent_str, arg_list);
        va_end(arg_list);
        return result;
}

(gdb) b 1234 if have_string && strstr(p, "hello")==0
```

Replace 1234 by the line number of `p=va_arg...`.
Edited: unshadow p and put have_string into the break cond.

Comment: You are shadowing p declared on top of function)

Comment: And it seems to me that `if (have_string) ...` should have an `else { p = "" }` for example to handle the case when there's no string. Then I use `strcmp` for strict string comparison.

Apart from that, works like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two parts to the question/answer:

1. How to get gdb to see parameters passed in the variable part? I don't think it has this ability, so you'll have to do something platform dependent. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242751/gdb-view-the-the-variable-argument-list) should work for x86_64. For 32bit it's more simple, because va_list is just an array of longs.
2. How to make a conditional breakpoint? gdb's `condition` command (documented [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Conditions.html#Conditions)) can help.

Comment: Yes it seems to work in general, the only open question remained is string comparison in breakpoint condition

Answer (score 0):

You would have to analyse the guts of your implementation's `va_list` type. E.g. it could be a pointer to an array of pointers, one of them (probably the first) pointing to "hello". Then teach your debugger to break on this condition.