# Why are not all printf arguments shown in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

I am playing with gdb to debug and analyze simple C programs, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
   int i = 8;

   printf("Your lucky number is %d\n", i);
}
```

When I debug in dbg and stop at `printf` call, gdb sees only the first argument, but not the second:

```
(gdb) break "printf"
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004c0
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/sq/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, __printf (format=0x4006f4 "Your lucky number is %d\n") at printf.c:28
28      printf.c: No such file or directory.
```

Why is that? And how to see the rest? Is it specific to printf?

(glibc 2.23, gcc 5.4, gdb 7.11.1 if that's relevant)

Comment: because of the variable arguments probably

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gdb | view the the variable argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242751/gdb-view-the-the-variable-argument-list)

Comment: OK. `varargs` is what makes it special. And how to see them? The other question doesn't make it obvious to me.

Comment: that's probably because it's _not_ obvious. Sounds difficult to achieve

Comment: I would do "down" then "print i" to get the value (from caller function)

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre and the special way the printf family is treated by some compiles (analysing the format string if possible during the compilation), makes it even more special.

Comment: Maybe XY problem. What do you want to achieve exactly? there are ways like looking at the caller, so what's preventing you to do this?

Comment: I am trying to understand here, so maybe it's just I need an explanation for how varargs are treated when making a call. If the answer says "you can do `frame X`, then `Y`", I am fine with this.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki after having reached the printf statement, you can do "down" to get to the caller. But you cannot get argument values automatically, you have to read the caller args and print them.